# Can we use GitHub actions in order to get the GitHub release tag and use it in the repo code for version?

Tags: github, github-actions

Attempted to use the below code to cause the GitHub actions to start when the release tag is published, but it isn't working.

```yaml
name: Update Values on Release

on:
  release:
    types: [ published ]  # Trigger only on published releases

jobs:
  update_values:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            git config --global user.email "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
            git config --global user.name "pxjssjsjx"
            release_tag=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
            # Update the value in the specified file (replace with your details)
            npx yaml-update -f hackkerRankSolutions/actions.yaml version=$release_tag
            git add hackkerRankSolutions/actions.yaml
            git commit -m "Update version to $release_tag in actions.yaml"
            git push origin main
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the repository code to get version values"? Could you give us an example of how you'd like to use the release tag?

Comment: If you meant to have version tags locally, you can use `git log --no-walk --tags --oneline`.

Comment: @SadraSabouri  Actually I meant how we can get the GitHub release tag through GitHub actions and use the same for the versioning of the repo in the code

Comment: @amanchhabra Do you want to write a Github Action that gets the version of the release tag and changes the version number in your files and commits it? Please show us a clear example.

Comment: @Schwern I have updated the code . Please check this and let me know how I can improve the code to inculate the required changes

Comment: I have also created a release in my own repo but even though its didn't trigger any GitHub actions

Comment: The problem is you tag a release and *then* change, commit, and push the version number. That means the release won't have the new version number! Usually you change the version number in the code and the release process reads the version number from the code.